# I have one javascript error in my IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery

> "Object doesn't support this property or method"

It's this line.

```
pthumb = $("#pthumb").attr("src");
```

Does anyone know why?

Comment: I have Jquery, and this works in Firefox/Chrome perfectly.

Comment: Are you including any other javascript libraries?

Comment: Can you post some markup and/or more of your code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Object doesn't support this property or method - IE 7/8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19800334/object-doesnt-support-this-property-or-method-ie-7-8)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a javascript variable called "pthumb" and a DOM element with the id "pthumb", and IE's JS engine could be trying to use the wrong one.

If you have a function also called "pthumb" then IE could also be trying perform this action on the function object.

The last thing to try is to make sure you are using "var" when declaring "pthumb" in the Javascript. i.e.:

```
var pthumb = $("#pthumb").attr("src");
```

Comment: I changed all the variable names and nothing was wrong

Comment: @alex, after you changed the names, the error still occurs?

Comment: correct, you're correct!

Comment: Cool, glad I could help. I looked into this in more detail to try and remember what else I learned when I first encountered it. I have updated my answer with the other possibilities. Once again IE's error messages are of very little help!

Answer (score 1):

Are you ensuring the DOM is ready?

```
$(document).ready(function(){  

    //wrap your code in document-ready check

    pthumb = $("#pthumb").attr("src");  

});
```

Comment: Well, this is a function that I call.

Comment: This is likely it.  Always use $(document).ready(), it saves a lot of trouble.

edit after seeing the above: are you sure the DOM is ready when the function is called?

Comment: @alex: So you do already call `$(document).ready()`??? Sorry I don't understand your comment.

Answer (score 0):

you could double check the plain javascript method:

```
var jthumb= document.getElementById('pthumb').attributes['src'].value;
try{
pthumb = $("#pthumb").attr("src");
}
catch(er){
alert(er.message + '\n'+jthumb)
}
```

If you don't catch the error, the element is not yet ready.