# Object doesn't support this property or method - IE 7/8

Tags: javascript

Any idea why this won't work in IE 7/8? (works fine in IE 9 and 10, FF and Chrome)

When I click the "Send" button, the console shows :

```
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support this property or method 
script.1383689376.js, line 94 character 3
(Line 94) : token = $("#token").val();
```

HTML:

```
<div class="comment_heading">Leave a Comment</div>
<div class="post_comment">
<textarea name="txtpostcomment" id="txtpostcomment-'.$postid.'" class="txtpostcomment"></textarea>
<button class="btnpostcomment" id="btnpostcomment-'.$postid.'" onclick="comment('.$postid.');" type="button">Send</button>
<input type="hidden" name="token" id="token" value="'.$_SESSION['token'].'">
<script>document.getElementById("txtpostcomment-'.$postid.'").focus();</script>
</div>
```

Script:

```
comment = function(postid1)
{
    txt =  $('#txtpostcomment-'+postid1);
    btn =  $('#btnpostcomment-'+postid1);

    comment1 = $(txt).val();
    token = $("#token").val();

    $(btn).css('background-image', 'url(/comments/submit-busy.gif)');
    $(btn).attr('disabled', true);
    $(btn).attr('disabled', true);
    ....
    ....
}
```

Comment: Does `$ === jQuery`? Is `jQuery.noConflict()` being used? And, what version of jQuery are you using? If you're trying jQuery 2.x, it [doesn't support IE 6 - 8](http://jquery.com/browser-support/).

Comment: I'm using jQuery 1.8.3 - I heard 1.10.x had issues with older browsers. Also no, jQuery.noConflict() is not being used.

Comment: 1.10.x should work fine with older browser. But, possibly not with older plugins as they may be using some of the API that's been [removed](http://api.jquery.com/category/removed/) from earlier versions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line of HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" name="token" id="token" value="'.$_SESSION['token'].'">
```

creates a property of the global object named "token" that is a reference to the input element.

In this line:

```
  token = $("#token").val();
```

you have an undeclared identifier. When this line is executed, IE tries to create a global variable *token* (because of the undeclared variable) but because there already is one (the aforementioned DOM element), IE throws an error.

Why IE doesn't simply assign the new value is a question that's been asked for over a decade, you won't get a sensible answer.

The simple fix is to **declare all variables**.

It is particularly bad to use a function expression to assign to an undeclared variable. It has zero benefits over a function declaration and has some serious drawbacks (you've just discovered one). So always declare variables in an appropriate scope and always use function declarations unless you have a very good reason to use a function expression.